# How to use my own area photo as a location map?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps

I'm writing web application with an interactive campus map.
I have my own area map photo which i want to use as the map
and i need to be able to convert geolocation coordinates to this photo and add some layers (like friends' location etc).

Is there any javascript library that may help me?

an example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful for you:
https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685872?hl=en&ref_topic=1685871
Good luck!